# Translating YouTube video title and description | V3 API

Tags: json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For the last few hours, I have been trying to find a solution to updating/uploading videos to many different languages throw the YouTube V3 API.
I can set the defaultLanguage,

```
"defaultLanguage": string
```

I can set video title and description,

```
   "title": string,
   "description": string,
```

or maybe there is a way of uploading many different snippets in different languages?

```
"snippet": {
 "publishedAt": datetime,
 "channelId": string,
 "title": string,
 "description": string,
 "thumbnails": {
   (key): {
     "url": string,
     "width": unsigned integer,
     "height": unsigned integer
   }
 },
```

I don't see a way of translating the title and descriptions.

I see that it might be possible to do with the "localized" property but, I do not know if it is even possible or if it is the best way to do it.

```
"localized": {
  "title": string,
  "description": string
},
```

I would like to have some suggestions since I'm so new to YouTube API and I find this would be a very easy question to answer if you knew the answer, I do not expect any code or a complex solution but just to be guided, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes I know, but, as the title says, all I want is a way of translating the video title and description to many languages, but I see no way of uploading the translated text

Comment: I don't need help translating anything, just uploading the translated text

Comment: damn, do you know if they are going to implement it?

Comment: It does support translated text, check my answer out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, localizations is what it's called.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.update

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=localizations&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "id": "kE7dYgd3F8E",  //https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_id=kE7dYgd3F8E
 "localizations": {
  "es-do": {           //local codes, http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.php
   "title": "Translated title",
   "description": "Translated description"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's very bad documented by Google/Youtube, but it works!